# How do I make TODOs not show up as errors in eclim?

Tags: eclipse, vim, eclim

I just started using eclim (combined with YouCompleteMe), and it's great.  There is one thing that's bothering me, though, and I can't figure out how to fix it.  The syntax checker runs on file saves, which is good, but it shows TODOs in the file as errors.  So, in the error column on the left side of the window, an error appears when there's a TODO in the file.  I've searched through all of eclim's vim files, tried a couple of eclim settings (`g:EclimTodoSearchPattern` and `g:EclimTodoSearchExtensions`), and none of those fixed the problem.  Indeed, it seems like eclim's `:ProjectTodo` and `:Todo` commands aren't what's causing this, because they produce a different kind of error and location list (different colors).

I'm thinking that eclim gets a list of issues from eclipse, including eclipse's task tags (which in turn are automatically generated from any TODO text), and that's what it shows.  So I tried to find a way to get eclipse not to show the task tag, but that was also unsuccessful.  I can get task tags to not show up in the "Tasks" view in eclipse, but I can't get them to be removed from the file itself.  Any idea of what I can do here?  I would really like to be able to see a real syntax error with eclim, fix it, and see the left error bar go away, so that I know I don't have any more compilation errors.  I don't want a TODO to pretend that it's a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found one way to solve this problem, though it's not totally ideal.  Eclim has a "sign level" that determines what severity of message it gets from eclipse to show in the vim window.  It turns out that eclipse's task tags show up as severity level "warning", so if you set the sign level to something above "warning", the task tags no longer show up.  This is done with the following line in a .vimrc:

```
let g:EclimSignLevel = 2
```

It would be better if I could lower the severity on the eclipse side, so I could still see other "warning" messages.  There's probably a setting for that somewhere...

Comment: Just by chance, have you solved that? I have the same problem: I don't want to see marks for TODOs, but want see marks for real warnings.

Comment: Nope, I haven't found anything except the EclimSignLevel, sadly.